# Some thoughts on von Neumann algebras

Tags: operator-theory

My motivation is the discussion here [separating vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4727380/separating-vector).

Let $\mathcal{M}\subseteq \mathcal{B}(H_0)$ be a separably acting type $II_1$ factor with a normal faithful tracial state $\tau\colon \mathcal{M}\to \mathbb{C}$ and let $n\in\mathbb{N}, n\geq 2.$ Then, $$\tau_n\colon M_n(\mathcal{M})\to \mathbb{C}, \tau_n([X_{i,j}])=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \tau(X_{i,i})$$ is a normal faithful tracial state of the separably acting type $II_1$ factor $M_n(\mathcal{M}).$ Consider the GNS construction for the state $\tau_n.$ There exist a separable Hilbert space $H_n,$ a normal representation $\pi_n\colon M_n(\mathcal{M})\to \mathcal{B}(H_n)$ and a unit vector $\xi_n\in H_n$ such that $\tau_n(X)=\langle{\pi_n(X)(\xi_n),\xi_n\rangle},\forall X\in M_n(\mathcal{M}).$ Recall that the algebra $M_n(\mathcal{M})$ acts on $H_n$ via the action $X(\omega):=\pi_n(X)(\omega), X\in M_n(\mathcal{M}), \omega\in H_n.$
We deduce that the vector $\xi_n$ separates $M_n(\mathcal{M}).$

Define now the separable Hilbert space $H=\oplus_{n=1}^{\infty}H_n,$ where $H_1=H_0.$ Every von Neumann algebra $M_n(\mathcal{M})$ acts on $H$ via $$X((\omega_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}})=(0,0,...,X(\omega_n),0,...), X\in M_n(\mathcal{M}), \omega_n\in H_n, \forall n\in\mathbb{N},$$ where $X(\omega_n)$ is the n-th coordinate. Now, the vector $\tilde{\xi_n}=(0,0,...,\xi_n,0,...)\in H,$ where $\xi_n$ is the n-th coordinate, separates $M_n(\mathcal{M}).$

Do you agree with the above text? Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that your action is not unital, which would often be required. But yes, $\tilde\xi_n$ is separating for your action. What is your question/what are you not certain about?

Comment: @MaoWao my goal is to have hyper-reflexive algebras. This is achieved e.g. if the algebra has separating vector.

Comment: But the image of $M_n(M)$ under your action is not a von Neumann algebra on $H$ as it is not unital.

Comment: Dear @MaoWao thank you so much. I have to find an alternative path.